# Where is jboss.server.config.url set in JBoss 5?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss5.x

I am facing a rather strange problem with an installation of JBoss 5.0.1 I have to deploy a webapp on.

In my webapp I try:

```
System.getProperty("jboss.server.config.url")
```

to get at the "conf"-dir. (And subsquently read a few files) On my development-machine this worked just fine, but in the deployment environment the aforementioned property appears to be the empty String ("").

Does anyone know why that could be and how to change it?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it does not work properly at yours, but you can change any JBoss property, just open `run.conf` file, and add line like at the end (at least JAVA_OPTS should be defined before):

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djboss.server.config.url=new_path"
```

for Windows should work (in `run.conf.bat`):

```
set JAVA_OPTS = %JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.server.config.url=new_path
```

this way you can change any property. Like Kevin D. already wrote, take a look at [JBoss Properties](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProperties), `jboss.server.config.url` is just `$jboss.server.home.url/conf`, so maybe something wrong with jboss.server.home.url variable, you can specify its value.. In its turn its value is `$jboss.server.base.url/$jboss.server.name`, check them etc. So you could find real cause of it... Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

It may rely on your JBOSS_Home being set in your environment variables.

This...article/list seems to indicate that all the JBOSS properties are built up from this http://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossProperties